# Enable/disable Opsview notifications from CLI

Tags: rest, command-line-interface, nagios, opsview

How can I enable/disable Opsview notifications from command line ?

As far as I read the Opsview REST API does only support GET requests.

I am currently using an old version of Opsview, 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work by sending a curl POST request

```
curl -s -c - 'http://opsviewserver/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi'  -H 'Cookie: auth_tkt=YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN'  --data 'cmd_typ=12&cmd_mod=2&btnSubmit=Commit'  -o /dev/null
```

Use cmd_typ=11 or cmd_typ=12 to enable/disable notifications.

You get the auth_tkt token in the header response of a login POST request:

```
curl -s -c -    'http://opsviewserver/login'  --data 'login_username=USER&login_password=PASS&back=&app=OPSVIEW&login=Sign+in' --compressed -o /dev/null
```

More about opsview auth_tkt:
https://docs.opsview.com/doku.php?id=opsview-core:restapi#logging_in_to_the_api_via_authtkt